# Switching between audio devices on EOS.. Hotkeys? Wingpanel?

Tags: wingpanel, audio, indicator-sound

Im looking for an easy and quick way to switch between my audio devices, since i swap them daily. Headphones are conected to laptop, and speakers to monitor/hdmi.

Every time i need to open sound settings and switch manualy which can be a bit annoying and waste of time.

Is there some hotkeys combination that can be used? Or proper indicator switch for wingpanel? (i tried installing few but did not have sucess)

My level of technical knowledge on linux is begginer i believe, so keep that in mind :)

Thank you :pray:

Comment: I find the best way to do so is by installing "pavucontrol" with `sudo apt install pavucontrol`. Never couldn't figure out why this app is not installed by default.

Comment: Tnx! I installed it, but i don't see actual solution to the question. Quick swap between audio devices in wingpanel??, nor keybord shortcuts, at least im not aware of it.. ? Thats what im looking for